# Private Readonly Field and Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I couldnt quite grasp the readonly and the CategoryController constructor here, what is the necessity of private readonly constructor and assigning _db = db. My ApplicationDbContext class inherits from EF Dbcontext class and the options parameter is passed to the base class, what does this private readonly and the constructor do here and whats its necessity? Image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW8Zg.png

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public CategoryController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
```

Comment: Please include your code as text (copy/paste, then format as code).  Pictures are very much frowned upon on this site

Answer (score 4):

The concept is called Dependency Injection, you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage).

Basically, you're injecting the database context. You can create it in your class like `var context = new ApplicationDbContext()`, but the class becomes dependent on this exact implementation. In the future you might want to use other contexts (like `MongoDbContext` or something), but it won't be possible to pass them to this class cause they're of different types.

To solve it, you make all your contexts implement inteface (`IMyContext` for example), create readonly `IMyContext` field in your class and pass whatever you need in constructor.

Comment: Another possible advantage is using a DI/IoC container. That can allow you to ask the container for a `CategoyController`, and let the container resolve any dependencies.